# Users seeing Error "Attempt to de-reference a null object" when clicking "Send to Pardot" in Salesforce

Tags: pardot, sync

Users seeing Error:-

> Attempt to de-reference a null object

when clicking "Send to Pardot" in Salesforce

Right now this is isolated to 1 user, not all of them. But I gave no idea what is causing this. I don't have nay recent Pardot sync errors. and haven't made significant Salesforce or Pardot changes around the time this started.

Comment: Anything in the Apex debug log?

Comment: Nope, nothing in there.

Comment: Sounds like an internal failure within the Pardot managed package. Likely they would need to debug it from their end to see the underlying cause. Is there a stack trace along with that exception?

Comment: No that I can tell. I did contact Pardot support and the issue has been taken up to engineering, but I haven't hear back yet. And the issue still persists.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error when clicking "Send to Pardot." Not sure if another issue is related (I'm opening a case with support about it), but when creating a duplicate Lead in Salesforce (same email address), the Prospect is only created in Pardot if there is a difference in either the first or last names.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that SSO needed to be re-enabled for this user for the SFDC and Pardot user sync. Once I re-verified his CRM username, the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check if your connector user has CRM Username assigned and Verified in Pardot user admin and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did check these and they were good. but Pardot finally got back to me on the issue. Simple thing of re-verfiying the CRM username in the Pardot user profile